# Hibernate update statement with duplicate value in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Using MYSQL with hibernate.

This is my update statement.

The session.flush() and the session.clear() worry me but i dont know any other way to do it.

sessionFactory is autowired by spring.

This is in my dao implementation.

What is wrong with this code?

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateCurrency(CurrencyEntity currencyEntity) {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    //flush the session sending previously cached SQL statements to the database
    session.flush();
    //clear the session as we don't want to keep previous entities tracked.
    //this avoids the chance of a persistent instance with the same identifier causing problems for the update.
    session.clear();

    session.update(currencyEntity);

    //flush to send the update to the database so any errors are caught immediately
    session.flush();

}
```

Comment: if your `currencyEntity` was already stored in the database, ie it has the id not empty, you should first load/attach it from the session or use `saveOrUpdate`

Comment: Remove the first session.flush() and clear. Then use session.merge(entity); and then finally session.flush(); No need to call session.clear(). Try this and let me know.

Comment: that would work but i am trying to update if exists not merge, merge will also create it if it does not exist